# How to read assembly code output from objdump

Tags: c, disassembly, objdump

I have a `C` code that swaps two numbers.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void swap(int,int);        
void main( )
{
    int n1,n2;
    printf("Enter the two numbers to be swapped\n");
    scanf("%d%d",&n1,&n2);
    printf("\nThe values of n1 and n2 in the main function before calling the swap function are n1=%d n2=%d",n1,n2);
    swap(n1,n2);                                          
    printf("\nThe values of n1 and n2 in the main function after calling the swap function are n1=%d n2=%d",n1,n2);}

void swap(int n1,int n2)                           
{ 
    int temp;
    temp=n1;
    n1=n2;
    n2=temp;
    printf("\nThe values of n1 and n2 in the swap function after swapping are n1=%d n2=%d",n1,n2);
}
```

I have disassembled it using `objdump` and been trying to find out how the swap operation happens in machine level. I think this is the swap function.

```
000006b4 <swap>:
 6b4:   55                      push   %ebp
 6b5:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 6b7:   53                      push   %ebx
 6b8:   83 ec 14                sub    $0x14,%esp
 6bb:   e8 37 00 00 00          call   6f7 <__x86.get_pc_thunk.ax>
 6c0:   05 0c 19 00 00          add    $0x190c,%eax
 6c5:   8b 55 08                mov    0x8(%ebp),%edx
 6c8:   89 55 f4                mov    %edx,-0xc(%ebp)
 6cb:   8b 55 0c                mov    0xc(%ebp),%edx
 6ce:   89 55 08                mov    %edx,0x8(%ebp)
 6d1:   8b 55 f4                mov    -0xc(%ebp),%edx
 6d4:   89 55 0c                mov    %edx,0xc(%ebp)
 6d7:   83 ec 04                sub    $0x4,%esp
 6da:   ff 75 0c                pushl  0xc(%ebp)
 6dd:   ff 75 08                pushl  0x8(%ebp)
 6e0:   8d 90 c0 e8 ff ff       lea    -0x1740(%eax),%edx
 6e6:   52                      push   %edx
 6e7:   89 c3                   mov    %eax,%ebx
 6e9:   e8 72 fd ff ff          call   460 <printf@plt>
 6ee:   83 c4 10                add    $0x10,%esp
 6f1:   90                      nop
 6f2:   8b 5d fc                mov    -0x4(%ebp),%ebx
 6f5:   c9                      leave  
 6f6:   c3                      ret
```

I want to know how swap operation is happening inside registers, I know it has to be something like this.

```
push eax
mov eax, ebx
pop ebx
```

But I can't see anything similar to this. Since I'm new to these things, can someone please help me how to understand how this is happening. [Full output of the `objdump` is here.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FlHIHQnExy-SuXMxHBhIxZb7MdaXkQgZ/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: What's the purpose of this exercise?

Comment: SO works best for specific questions. The solution to *"hard to understand what each instruction is doing"* is to look up an assembly tutorial and read it.

Comment: your program does not swap number btw. use pointers to `n1` and `n2` like for `scanf`

Comment: How to read it? Carefully. And visit http://godbolt.com  And remember the compiler may optimize your code altogether and leave only statements with side effects, so there may not be any swapping code in assembly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get started with the assembly language you can check the following link:

http://patshaughnessy.net/2016/11/26/learning-to-read-x86-assembly-language